# Relative position with top in %

Tags: html, css

I have this sample code

```css
h2.pos_left {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="pos_left">This heading is moved left according to its normal position</h2>
```

I am trying to make relative work with top %. Is there a way to make this work?
Other option is to force absolute to go with the flow. 
My idea is to have few div that will take some % of the page, so they are responsive when window is smaller. If it's absolute and I make the window smaller that effect that doesn't go with the flow is irritating, since elements go on top of each other.

Any idea would be extremely useful.Perhaps some out of box idea

Comment: If you are clear about absolute should always resides inside relative. Then start seeing media queries for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `<html>` and `<body>` tag 100% height:

```css
h2.pos_left {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="pos_left">This heading is moved left according to its normal position</h2>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with angular 2. sorry. May be you should add this information in your question and add the tag angular 2 ;).

Answer (score 0):

and to make your divs responsive use this

```css
h2.pos_left {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   max-width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="pos_left">This heading is moved left according to its normal position</h2>
```